# Can pause a timed refresh if user is in a textarea

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok I took the answer you gave me and did this, but it doesnt work, I am probably missing something

```
 function setusersintext(inout){
    var userIsInTextArea = false;
    if($inout=='in'){
       userIsInTextArea = true;
    }else{
       userIsInTextArea = false;
    }
    }

  $(".refreshMe").everyTime(5000,function(i){
      if(!userIsInTextArea) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "refresh-me.php?id=<?php echo $get_id['id']; ?>&user=<?php echo $user; ?    >&user_name=<?php echo $user_name; ?>",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("ol#newupdates").prepend(html);

          }
        })
      }
   })
```

here is the textarea code.

```
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  
        id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>" 
        onfocus="myFocus(this);setusersintext(in);" 
        onblur="myBlur(this);setusersintext(out);">
  Write a comment...
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set up a flag when user sets focus to a text area and check that flag later.

```
 var userIsInTextArea = false;

 $('#commentText').focus(function() {
   userIsInTextArea = true;
 });

 $('#commentText').blur(function() {
   userIsInTextArea = false;
 });



  $(".refreshMe").everyTime(5000,function(i){
      if(!userIsInTextArea) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "refresh-me.php?id=<?php echo $get_id['id']; ?>&user=<?php echo $user; ?>&user_name=<?php echo $user_name; ?>",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("ol#newupdates").prepend(html);

          }
        })
      }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick answer. Going to test it now and will respond asap.

Comment: I have one more question... here is the textarea code

<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>" onfocus="myFocus(this);" onblur="myBlur(this);">Write a comment...</textarea>

where id="ctextarea+the message id, so that when they submit a comment ajax know which one to update... is there a way to have another id used?

Comment: Or can the onfocus onblur that is used in the textarea code trigger something at the top thanks so much

Comment: @JudyRobert: do you need clarifications on this one, or is it another, unrelated, question?

Comment: no its a related question, the textarea already has an id that can't be changed, but the textarea also has the onfocus & onblur, is there a way to check that, basically i need to know how to change on or the other to work with each other. Thanks

Comment: You could set up this flag and/or memorize active textarea id in your focus/blur handlers.

Comment: Im sorry I am a total newbie at javascript and ajax, how can I have the focus/blur handlers trigger the pause?
Really sorry...

Comment: @JudyRobert: you see my example with a flag? Can you make similar thing in your handlers that you already have?

Comment: Yes see your example and i would work perfect if the textarea didn't have an id that can't be changed. But I don't think I am understanding what I should do with the handlers. Should I do something like, onfocus="myFocus(this);(a function to set the userIsInTextArea ) " onblur="myBlur(this);

Thanks

Comment: @JudyRobert: you can do something like that, yes!

Comment: Here is what I did, but its not working, if you could help me please.
I will have to post it in different parts

Comment: function setusersintext(inout){
 var userIsInTextArea = false;
 if($inout=='in'){
    userIsInTextArea = true;
 }else{
    userIsInTextArea = false;
 }
}

  $(".refreshMe").everyTime(5000,function(i){
      if(!userIsInTextArea) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "refresh-me.php?id=<?php echo $get_id['id']; ?>&user=<?php echo $user; ?>&user_name=<?php echo $user_name; ?>",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("ol#newupdates").prepend(html);

          }
        })
      }
  })

Comment: here is the textarea code.  
  <textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>" onfocus="myFocus(this);setusersintext(in);" onblur="myBlur(this);setusersintext(out);">Write a comment...</textarea>

Comment: no it still refreshes, and it doesn't myFocus(this) or myBlur(this)... im sure its something small I am missing, cause i don't even know how to put 2 functions in a statement like that.